# Importing UTF-8 sql dump to a UTF-8 database, non-english characters are jumbled

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

Here are the settings of the source database:
[image]

and here are the settings of the database on the new server
[image]

When I use the export function on the source database, I set "Character set of the file:" to utf-8. I verified the dump and all the non-english characters are there as they should be.

I used the following command before uploading the database on the new server:
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Then I upload the dump on the new server. I use SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;
and under "collation" some columns have NULL and others have utf8_general_ci

But when I access the website all the non-english characters are jumbled like this: Ã©tÃ©

Can anyone please help me? I don't know much about mysql but I have looked around on google and stackoverflow and I couldn't fix it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You website charset needs to be utf-8 too.

Comment: I am using joomla. I copied the website files from the other server to the new server. If it was utf-8 on the old server, shouldn't it be utf-8 on the new server too? Anyway I don't think this is the problem. When I manually browse the tables of the uploaded dump on the new database, the non-english characters have disappeared and the jumbled characters are there.

Comment: See here http://i.imgur.com/YkKrx8L.jpg

Comment: check the response headers to see if the charset is utf-8

Comment: I have just tried issuing the following commands (after having dropped all the tables) but I get errors: SET character_set_client = utf8;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

SET character_set_connection = utf8;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: The response headers:
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

Comment: That look like request headers

Comment: You are right, sorry. The only thing that maybe related to this in the response headers is Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 03:23:18 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Set-Cookie: acd93c47bf8cd7e9c6bb9a9ae48924a9=2ba2feabc5c8b2786c25cc9272e85097; path=/ 
Set-Cookie: zijji_tpl=zijji; expires=Mon, 07-Jul-2014 03:23:19 GMT; path=/ 
Connection: close 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Try adding `content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` header to the page

Comment: I added AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 to htaccess. Here is the new response header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1. The problem is still there. I think the problem is in the database because when I browse the tables using phpmyadmin the problem is there.

Comment: If I enter the joomla administration page, remove the jumbled characters and replace them with what it should be, then the character shows up as intended.